# Best algorithm for feature detection in urban environment - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I'm using OpenCV library (C++) to extract detectors from 2 images coming from a video stream  taker from an aerial camera in order to, afterwards, find the matching points in successive images. i'm wondering which is the best algorithm to find robust detectors of a **urban environment**??

Ps. Actually I'm using SURF but when the images changes a little (because the camera is translating very slowly) the matchings between these descriptors become very few!

Comment: Have you tried dense sampling?

Comment: Did you tried SIFT? I know it is very similar to SURF, but usually it is much more robust. I use it for a very difficult task of matching and the results are highly better with SIFT than SURF. Also the change in your code is really small.

Comment: yeeeees, SIFT works much better! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try different aproaches give a try to [RoboRealm](http://www.roborealm.com)  , they have a trial version, you just put the algoritms and seems the results, for testing purposes even if you will use OpenCV its ok.